# match multiple terms in a string to determine topic

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to search a user-entered string against a list of known terms to determine a topic. That is, I maintain my own list of topics and related keywords, and want to match against the user-entered string to determine the topic(s) it relates to. However, I want to make sure multiple terms are "hit" to avoid false-positives.

e.g. based on the code:

```
//create a list of topic keywords
    List<string> CivilWar = new List<string>()
    {
        "Confederacy", "Union", "Civil War", "Lincoln", "Stonewall Jackson"

    };

    //does the user agent string exist in the list?
    bool isTopic = CivilWar.Exists(x => source.Contains(x));
return isTopic
```

the string "Stonewall Jackson fought for the Confederacy" returns a correct positive / true result, but the string "John Kennedy Toole wrote A Confederacy of Dunces" returns a false positive / true result.

How can I make sure multiple terms are required to score a positive?

Comment: Most probably you are looking for StartsWith

Comment: No, I am definitely not, since the keywords can appear anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool isTopic = CivilWar.Where(x => source.Contains(x)).Count() > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Count` instead of `Exists`, and make sure it is greater than 1 (*multi*-term):

```
//create a list of topic keywords
List<string> CivilWar = new List<string>()
{
    "Confederacy", "Union", "Civil War", "Lincoln", "Stonewall Jackson"
};

//does the user agent string exist in the list?
return CivilWar.Count(x => source.Contains(x)) > 1; //must be greater than 1
```